# C# function to convert DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

i want to convert a string variable which has the value in **mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM** to **mm/dd/yy**

How can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) and then `dateTimeVal.ToString("MM/dd/yy")`

Something like

```
string stringDate = "12-31-2010 01:59:59 AM";
DateTime dateTimeValue;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDate, "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTimeValue))
{
    string newStringValue = dateTimeValue.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(yourDateString).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Convert.To?? may throws exception, so it will be safer to use what @astander suggested.

Comment: ToDateTime() only works if your current culture matches. it will work if you have en-US but not if you have de-DE

Comment: @k3b you can give format information to ToDateTime if that is the problem and @Jani, you can use a try catch block which is what TryParse does on the backstage..

Comment: using a try/catch block is actually not what happens within DateTime.TryParse (it calls DateTimeParse.TryParseExact which in turn calls DateTimeParse.DoStrictParse which carries out a somewhat elaborate process) - I'm not sure where you source your information, but I would seek council of many in the future.